# Navigate through pages using Redux and React-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a series of pages to capture data from a user. I would like to use `Redux` with `React-Router`, to navigate through my pages, rather than link to each page manually.

I have a very simple `Router` setup.

```
import Screen1 from './components/Screen1';
import Screen2 from './components/Screen2';
import Screen3 from './components/Screen3';
import Screen4 from './components/Screen4';
import Screen5 from './components/Screen5';
import Screen6 from './components/Screen6';

let store = createStore(lydApp);

render(
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route path="/" component={Screen1} />
            <Route path="/1" component={Screen2} />
            <Route path="/2" component={Screen3} />
            <Route path="/3" component={Screen4} />
            <Route path="/4" component={Screen5} />
            <Route path="/5" component={Screen6} />
        </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And a very basic `reducer`:

```
import { NEXT_PAGE, PREVIOUS_PAGE } from '../constants/ActionTypes';

const initialState = [
  {
    title: 'Screen1',
    complete: 0,
  },
  {
    title: 'Screen2',
    complete: 0,
  },
  {
    title: 'Screen3',
    complete: 0,
  },
  {
    title: 'Screen4',
    complete: 0,
  },
  {
    title: 'Screen5',
    complete: 0,
  },
];

export default function PageChecker(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NEXT_PAGE:

    //somehow check page is complete and move to next page

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

how can I use my `NEXT_PAGE` action to navigate through my app?

Comment: Have you tried to use a thunk and call the history from there ? You should achieve this with a `hsitory.push(nextPage)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like like async action, but you have to have `redux-thunk` middleare https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk attached.

Here's example code:

```
export default function PageChecker(state = initialState, action) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case NEXT_PAGE:

        dispatch(go(`/page/${action.page + 1}`))

        return state;
      break;
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
}
```